# When duplicating an action in the NLA editoris it suposed to create a new source action each time?

Tags: nla-editor, actions

Like I said above, as of Blender 3.0 whenever I duplicate an action in the NLA editor it creates a new action entirely. Previously when you would duplicate an action in the editor, it would make another NLA Action Block called "NAME.001", but it wouldnt make a new action - the duplicate would reference the same source-action.

Is this a glitch or did they do this intentionally? I guess that this kinda makes more sense this way, but I am honestly a bit distraught because I think this will retroactively mess up a lot of my files if I open them in 3.0. I duplicate action blocks all the time, like when I have a walk cycle, then a pause, then walk again.

Do I now have to use a NLA block (excuse me, I do not know the technical term for actions in the NLA editor) modifier in order to turn off the walk cycle from X to Y frames?

I really hope this is a bug, it seems counterintuitive to how other instance based systems in Blender work, but I guess they overhauled that as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it worked the same way in the previous versions. If you use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> it will create a new action. You need to use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the same action. If you want the action to be repeated you can also simply select the strip, open the *NLA N panel > Strip > Action Clip >* and tweak the *Repeat* value.

Comment: Ohhhhh thank you so much! That is very insightful, I never realized Alt could be used in that way. I bet its becuase I use 3-button input normally, and 3.0 turned that off, which previously changed the purpose of alt for me 

I'd give you an upvote but I dont have enough reputation, but tysm!